# JS getAttribute() from HTML is returning always null

Tags: javascript, html, getattribute

Hi I would like to make a hide/show menu. I used a div to define my menu. It's display attribute is none when the resolution smaller then a tablet screen. I used  another div's onclik="" as a buttom to start the function. In the function I am trying to get display's condition to block the bugs. When I get it if it's not shown I will change the attribute to block.

```css
/* ************************************************* Ortak Masaüstü Başlangıç************************************************* */
#header {
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1;
    background-color: white;
}
#header img {
    height: 100%;
}
#header img:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
#orta {
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding-top: 56px;
    background-image: url(img\back.png);
}
#orta .sol {
    width: 15%;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
}
#orta .merkez {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 20px 5px #aaaaaa;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 20px 5px #aaaaaa;
    box-shadow: 10px 20px 5px #aaaaaa;
    float: left;
    background-color: #2eb2ff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.75;
    padding: 20px 20px 105px 20px;
}
#orta .merkez h2 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#orta .merkez .icerik {
    height: auto;
}
#orta .sag {
    width: 15%;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
}


/* ************************************************* Ortak Masaüstü Bitiş************************************************* */







#orta .merkez .icerik button {
    width: 100%;
    padding:2px;
    margin-top:2px;
}


#mySidenav a {
    position: fixed;
    left: -80px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 110px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#mySidenav a:hover {
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #aaaaaa;
}
.acilirmenu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 40px;
    height: 33px;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    background-color: #555;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
#uccizgi1, #uccizgi2, #uccizgi3 {
    width: 34px;
    height: 5px;
    background: black;
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition:0.3s;
}



#news {
    top: 60px;
    background-color: #555;
    z-index: 1;
}
#blog {
    top: 122px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    z-index: 1;
}
#projects {
    top: 184px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    z-index: 1;
}
#about {
    top: 246px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    z-index: 1;
}
#contact {
    top: 308px;
    background-color: #555;
    z-index: 1;
}
footer {
    background-color: #092834;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -100px; /* altAlan yuksekliginin eksi degeri */
    height: 100px;
    clear:both;
    color: #347B98;
    opacity:0.8;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
footer img {
    width: 25px;
}
footer img:hover {
    width: 25px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
footer .backtotop {
    float: right;
}
footer .backtotop img{
    width: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    bottom: 25px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    resize: vertical;
}

label {
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}

.col-25 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.col-75 {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}




/* ************************* Projeler ************************* */
.merkez .icerik .projeler {
    height: 250px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    border: solid 2px #2fa362;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
}
#orta .merkez .icerik .projeler .projebaslik {
    text-align: center;
}
#orta .merkez .icerik .projeler .projeaciklama {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
}
/* ************************* Bir Sorum Var ************************* */
#orta .sag button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    right: 0px;
}


/* ************************* Life V3.0 ************************* */

#orta .merkez .icerik #solust{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #AAA;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#orta .merkez .icerik #sagust{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #BBB;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#orta .merkez .icerik #solort{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#orta .merkez .icerik #sagort{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#orta .merkez .icerik #solalt{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#orta .merkez .icerik #sagalt{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/**************************************************************************************/
/* ****************************************************** Çözünürlük 768 pikselin altına düştüğünde. ****************************************************** */
@media (max-width : 768px) {

#mySidenav a {
    left: -150px;
}
#mySidenav a:hover {
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #aaaaaa;
}

#orta .sol .sidenav .acilirmenu {
    opacity: 1;
}

#news {
    top: 60px;
    background-color: #555;
    z-index: 1;
}
#blog {
    top: 122px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    z-index: 1;
}
#projects {
    top: 184px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    z-index: 1;
}
#about {
    top: 246px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    z-index: 1;
}
#contact {
    top: 308px;
    background-color: #555;
    z-index: 1;
}


.merkez .icerik .projeler {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
}


#orta .sol {
    width: 2%;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
}
#orta .merkez {
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 20px 5px #aaaaaa;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 20px 5px #aaaaaa;
    box-shadow: 10px 20px 5px #aaaaaa;
    float: left;
    background-color: #2eb2ff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.75;
    padding: 20px 20px 105px 20px;
}

#orta .merkez h2 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#orta .sag {
    width: 2%;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
}
#orta .sag .sidenav a {
    left: -70px;
}

#mySidenav a:active {
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #aaaaaa;
}

footer {
    background-color: #092834;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -100px; /* altAlan yuksekliginin eksi degeri */
    height: 100px;
    clear:both;
    color: #347B98;
    opacity:0.8;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
}
footer img {
    width: 20px;
}
footer img:hover {
    width: 20px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
footer .backtotop img {
    width: 40px;
    right: 8px;
    bottom: 35px;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

#orta .merkez .icerik #solust{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #AAA;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#orta .merkez .icerik #sagust{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #BBB;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#orta .merkez .icerik #solort{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#orta .merkez .icerik #sagort{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#orta .merkez .icerik #solalt{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#orta .merkez .icerik #sagalt{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
}/* Düşük Çözünürlük Bitişi */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- META Etiketleri -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="tr"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Mahir Yıldızhan. Personal web site. Kişisel internet sayfası."/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Mahir Yıldızhan, mahiryildizhan, Bir Sorum Var, ALES, ALES Soruları"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Mahir Yıldızhan">
    <meta name="owner" content="Mahir Yıldızhan"/>
    <title>Mahir Yıldızhan | Haberler</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="js/func.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

var x = document.getElementById("news").getAttribute("display");
if ( x == "none") {...} else if (x == "block") {...};
$durum = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#orta .sol .sidenav .acilirmenu").click(function(){
        if ($durum==1) {
            document.getElementById("uccizgi2").style.background ="#a2f362";
            document.getElementById("uccizgi1").style.background ="#a2f362";
            document.getElementById("uccizgi2").style.transform ="rotate(90deg)";
            document.getElementById("uccizgi3").style.display ="none";
            document.getElementById("uccizgi1").style.transform ="translateY(11px)";
            document.getElementById("news").style.left ="-15px";
            $("#mySidenav a").hide();
            $durum=0;
        } else if ($durum==0) {
            document.getElementById("uccizgi2").style.background ="black";
            document.getElementById("uccizgi1").style.background ="black";
            document.getElementById("uccizgi2").style.transform ="rotate(0deg)";
            document.getElementById("uccizgi3").style.display ="block";
            document.getElementById("uccizgi1").style.transform ="translateY(0px)";
            document.getElementById("news").style.left ="-30px";
            $("#mySidenav a").show();
            $durum=1;
        };

    });
});
</script>





</head>
<body onload="acilis()">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/LogoG.png"></a>

    </div>
    <div id="orta">
        <div class="sol">
            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                <div class="acilirmenu">
                    <div id="uccizgi1"></div>
                    <div id="uccizgi2"></div>
                    <div id="uccizgi3"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="haberler.html" id="news">Haberler</a>
                <a href="https://mahiryildizhancom.blogspot.com.tr/" target="_blank" id="blog">Blog</a>
                <a href="projeler.html" id="projects">Projeler</a>
                <a href="hakkimda.html" id="about">Hakkımda</a>
                <a href="iletisim.html" id="contact">İletişim</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="merkez">
            <h2><p>Anlamsız Veriden Anlamlı Bilgiye...</p></h2>
            <div class="icerik">
                <button>BASLA</button>
                <div style="background:#56aaaa;height:110px;width:80px;position:absolute;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sag">
        </div>
    </div>

<footer>
    <center>Mahir Yıldızhan | <a href="mailto:mahiryildizhan.com@gmail.com">mahiryildizhan.com@gmail.com</a> 
        <p><a href="https://mahiryildizhancom.blogspot.com.tr/" target="_blank"><img src="img\Blogger.png"></a>|
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mahir.yildizhan" target="_blank"><img src="img\Facebook.png"></a>|
        <a href="https://github.com/m4h1r" target="_blank"><img src="img\Github.png"></a>|
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/mhryldzhn/" target="_blank"><img src="img\Instagram.png"></a>|
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mahiryildizhan/" target="_blank"><img src="img\Linkedin.png"></a>|
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/8455233/mahir-y%C4%B1ld%C4%B1zhan" target="_blank"><img src="img\StackOverFlow.png"></a>|
        <a href="https://twitter.com/mahiryildizhan" target="_blank"><img src="img\Twitter.png"></a>|
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzSIjra8EKWS6fIJfNjTQIw" target="_blank"><img src="img\Youtube.png"></a>
    </center> <div class="backtotop"><a href="#top"><img src="img\back-to-top.png" alt="En Üste Dön"></a> v2018-05 </div>
</footer>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>


<!-- Yapılacaklar Listesi 
    1-) Bir Sorum Var! listesine 5 video yükle.
    2-) Bir Sorum Var bu göresel ile güncelle.
1SorumVar
-->
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Code, both html and js, and keep it clean and to a minimum we dotn need the whole page just the snippet

Comment: @wiesion how do you link that, i dont know where to get a reference to that post, am i suppose to keep it bookmarked or smth?

Comment: I insert all my code.

Comment: loving variable names

Comment: I would like to change "durum" with "x" I will store the display attributes value in x and If my menu is hidden, when I click "acilirmenu" it will make menu shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is trying to access an element that has not been parsed by the browser.
You should place your script below the element you want to access. In addition the element with id="news" has no display attribute, and that's not even a valid html attribute

Comment: Hi, normaly I use linked Js file to code scripts. But it's still same returns null.

Comment: use the "defer" attribute to true for external scripts or place it at the bottom of the page

Comment: I define attributes on css file. Is that matter? and can you show me a small sample. Thanks

Comment: I tried also defer usage. It's still returning null.

Comment: I said earlier that the element with `id="news"` has no display attribute in the html definition